# update data into an empty table with the data from another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables - XYZ (140 cols.) with no data and ABC (65 cols.) with data.

I need to wirte a sql query in such a way that the data certain cols. in table ABC gets updated into the table XYZ. I do have mapping for the columns. But, there is no Primary key in the first table (XYZ, which is created).

The table XYZ is just a skeleton with absolutely no data in it!

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you tried using the Query Designer in Access to build an [Append Query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-HA010076526.aspx)?

Comment: I did try using the Query designer, but in vain!

Comment: By "in vain", do you mean you: didn't understand how to use query builder; designed the query but got an error when trying to run it; were able to design and run the query, but no records were copied to XYZ?  When using the query builder to perform an Append query into a table with more columns, you can simple omit them and they will be filled with NULLs.  You simply create mappings for all the columns you do have.

Comment: I was able to use the QUERY BUILDER to design the query, but when trying to run it, there was no data appened into the destination table!

Comment: Are you using any criteria in the query?

Comment: yes, there is an exclude column in the table with 140 cols. I have used a where condition "EXCLUDE IS NULL"

Comment: If you take off that condition, do the records transfer? (you can always delete them after this test)  If so, it would indicate that none of the values in the "EXCLUDE" field are NULL.  What type of data does the "EXCLUDE" field have? It might be filled with empty strings "" instead of NULLS.

Comment: got it fixed..!! its the data in the "Exclude" column thats causing a glitch in the INSERT INTO Statement. Thank you @Blackhawk for the guidance! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into XYZ
Select ABC.*
From ABC;